Issue with React Checkbox Selection in Table Rows
I'm working on a React application where I have a table displaying student data fetched from an API. Each row in the table includes a checkbox to select the student for further processing. However, I'm facing an issue where clicking on one checkbox seems to automatically select another checkbox in a different row.
I implemented a React table component using Material-UI's Checkbox to allow users to select students from a fetched list. Each row in the table represents a student with a checkbox for selection.
I expected that clicking on a checkbox would only select or deselect the student in the corresponding row without affecting other rows. This means each checkbox should operate independently of others.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Checkbox, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableContainer, TableHead, TableRow, Button, Grid, Typography, Container } from '@mui/material';
import AddCircleOutlineIcon from '@mui/icons-material/AddCircleOutline';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
import Navbar from '@/components/navbar';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  container: {
    paddingTop: theme.spacing(8),
    paddingBottom: theme.spacing(8),
    color: theme.palette.text.primary,
  },
  form: {
    maxWidth: 600,
    margin: 'auto',
  },
  button: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(2),
  },
  tableContainer: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(4),
  },
}));

export default function AdmitCardPage() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [students, setStudents] = useState([]);
  const [selectedStudents, setSelectedStudents] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStudents();
  }, []);

  const fetchStudents = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3002/students');
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to fetch students');
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      setStudents(data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching students:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleSelectStudent = (student) => {
    setSelectedStudents((prevSelectedStudents) => {
      if (prevSelectedStudents.some((s) => s.id === student.id)) {
        return prevSelectedStudents.filter((s) => s.id !== student.id);
      } else {
        return [...prevSelectedStudents, student];
      }
    });
  };

  const handleSave = () => {
    console.table(selectedStudents);
    // Replace with logic to save selected students
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Container className={classes.container}>
        <Typography variant="h4" align="center" gutterBottom>
          Admit Card
        </Typography>

        <Grid container spacing={2} className={classes.form}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              onClick={fetchStudents}
              className={classes.button}
              startIcon={<AddCircleOutlineIcon />}
            >
              Fetch Students
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>

        <TableContainer className={classes.tableContainer}>
          <Table>
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell>Select</TableCell>
                <TableCell>Student Name</TableCell>
                {/* Add more headers as needed */}
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>

            <TableBody>
              {students.map((student) => (
                <TableRow key={student.id}>
                  <TableCell>
                    <Checkbox
                      checked={selectedStudents.some((s) => s.id === student.id)}
                      onChange={() => handleSelectStudent(student)}
                      color="primary"
                    />
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell>{student.name}</TableCell>
                  {/* Add more cells as needed */}
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>

        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary"
          onClick={handleSave}
          className={classes.button}
        >
          Save Selected Students
        </Button>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}



I copied your code into a sandbox ( https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/material-ui-forked-7v5g4s?file=%2FAdmitCardPage.js%3A48%2C19 ), replacing your fetch call with a hardcoded array. The checkboxes seem to work properly.
You should check the response from your fetchStudents method - there might be students with duplicate ids, causing the wrong checkbox to check.

Thank you, instead using id, i provide unique student_id. Its working. @EvanLauer
